# Group a dictionary of objects by object property

Tags: python

I've got a dict of objects of class `Metric`. Each `Metric` object has a property called `category` (e.g., "cat1", "cat2", ...). What's the smartest way to arrange the dict by `category`?

My solution right now is to make a set of all the categories by iterating thru each object, then iterating again and assigning each object to a category, but I'm thinking there may be a more efficient way?

What I have:

```
{'a': <__main__.Metric at 0xb1e3470>,
 'b': <__main__.Metric at 0xb14f7b8>,
 'c': <__main__.Metric at 0xb160828>,
 'd': <__main__.Metric at 0x5ee9128>,
 'e': <__main__.Metric at 0xb14f550>,
 'f': <__main__.Metric at 0xb14ff98>,
 'g': <__main__.Metric at 0xb14fa58>,
...}
```

What I would like:

```
{'cat1': [<__main__.Metric at 0xb160828>, ...]
 'cat2': [<__main__.Metric at 0xb14f550>, ...],
...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for obj in your_dict.values():
    my_dict[obj.category].append(obj)
    #          ^ object category as key
```

where `your_dict` is the structure holding your current dict mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
cat_dict = dict((obj.category, obj) for obj in metric_dict.itervalues())
```

Comment: Based on the desired output, values of dict is `list` which makes me think that there is possibility of duplicate category

Comment: yeah, this only gives one metric per category. there are many

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
category_dict = {}
for obj in metric_dict.values():
   cat = obj.category
   if cat not in category_dict:
     category_dict[cat] = []
   category_dict[cat].append(obj)
```

This should give you a dictionary of of categories with a list of metrics:

```
{ 'cat_1': [Metric, Metric, ...],
    'cat_2': [Metric, Metric, ...],
    ...
  }
```